# Php length of cyrillic string doubles its value

Tags: php, string, double, strlen

Hello here it is the problem:
when i get to the $_POST latin string strilen() works perfectly, but when i get cyrillic string strlen() doubles its value here is the code:

```
$word = $_POST['word'];
echo strlen($word) . '<br>'; //input: abc -> returns 3, input: абв -> returns 6 
var_dump($word); //input: abc -> returns string 'abc' (length=3), input: абв -> returns string 'абв' (length=6)
```

Do you have some ideas?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`strlen` does not double anything, it simply reports what the situation is. Specifically, it reports *how many bytes* -- and not *how many characters* -- make up the string. That is because `strlen` does not have any knowledge of what a "character" is, and blindly assumes that 1 byte = 1 character. Therefore we say that "`strlen` is not multibyte-aware".

In your case, it seems that the browser submits UTF-8 encoded data to the server. In UTF-8, cyrillic is two bytes per character.

If you want to find out the number of characters in the string, use the multibyte-aware [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php):

```
echo mb_strlen($word, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: mm how to fix it? or just to devide it by 2?

Comment: @FretwoakDukov: How to fix what exactly?

Comment: I just want when i get the variable from the post to cut the last four characters into sub string so i do this:
$stringLength = strlen($string);
return substr($string, $stringLength - 4, $stringLength);
but... doesnt work well

Comment: @FretwoakDukov: `mb_substr`. You want the `mb_` functions. You cannot use any of the pure string functions when you work with multibyte text.

Answer (score 4):

Try `mb_strlen()` if you're dealing with multi-byte characters.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get length in the terms of characters (not bytes) use a multi-byte version of strlen: mb_strlen: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php